# Question about an activity killed by system

Tags: android

Suppose root activity A starts activity B, and then activity B starts activity C. Then the current task stack contains A, B, C.

Suppose now the system memory got low, and OS killed activity B. After that, the user pressed back key to exit activity C. My question is, after activity C exits, will activity B be recreated and shows up, or will activity A shows up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless activity B called finish(), it should show up again.

Comment: When OS kills activity B, will OS call B's finish()? I think it will. What do you think?

Comment: The OS tries to make this all completely invisible to the user, so you will get the expected behavior of Activity B coming back.  It I don't know if the OS will call the finish() method, but as long as YOU don't call it everything will work out.

Comment: @Kai -- Nope. When another activity comes to the foreground, your activity's `onPause()` method gets called. After that, if the system decides it needs the resources, it will kill your activity's process with no further calls to your code. Boom. The docs on [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) make good reading.

Comment: Do I understand correctly? In the scenario in my question, activity B will be recreated (onCreate() of B will be called) and displayed?

Comment: Yes. This is detailed in the flow diagram for [component lifecycles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles).